# New version of VSTO after 4.0

Tags: vsto, ms-office

Do you know something about future of VSTO for new Office 2012?
Are there some rumours of what the new VSTO can offer and whether the VSTO is not a dead end?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevpreview/thread/7c928b03-82a7-4399-bac2-d7fe6154fc5f